# str Numpy array fill

Tags: python, numpy

I've created a numpy array (str) name arrnumpy[128,128,16] , and I have str object name input1=0000444440120010
I would tp store this object (input1) to location arrnumpy[127,127] , so if I access the it , I would like to see as follow:

**Code**

```
input1='0000444440120010'
arrnumpy= np.empty([128,128,16], dtype='str')
arrnumpy[127,127]=input1
print(arrnumpy[127,127])
```

**Output**

```
['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
```

**Desired output**

```
arrnumpy[127,127] [0] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [1] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [2] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [3] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [4] =4
arrnumpy[127,127] [5] =4
arrnumpy[127,127] [6] =4
arrnumpy[127,127] [7] =4
arrnumpy[127,127] [8] =4
arrnumpy[127,127] [9] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [10] =1
arrnumpy[127,127] [11] =2
arrnumpy[127,127] [12] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [13] =0
arrnumpy[127,127] [14] =1
arrnumpy[127,127] [15] =0
```

Comment: `arrnumpy[127,127] = list(input1)`

Comment: do you want your output as strings or integers ?

Comment: @joostblack as string . I'm work on Dicom Image encryption , so i extract pixel data as numpy array , then I will input it as string in Serpent Algorithm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.